Why is my concatenated video using FFmpeg longer than the sum of the input videos?
I concatenated a few videos with that FFmpeg  command:
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i "list_videos.txt" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:3 -copy_unknown -tag:2 gpmd -c copy "abc.mp4"

with list_videos.txt containing:
file 'a.MP4'
file 'b.MP4'
file 'c.MP4'

to my surprise, abc.mp4 is much longer that the sum of the lengths of a.MP4, b.MP4, 'c.MP4:




Name
Date Modified
Type
Size
Length




abc.mp4
12/2/2024 5:44 PM
MP4 Video File
10,361,345
23:36:00


c.MP4
12/2/2024 5:40 PM
MP4 Video File
2,539,328
00:05:47


b.MP4
12/1/2024 10:23 PM
MP4 Video File
3,912,750
00:08:54


a.MP4
12/1/2024 10:14 PM
MP4 Video File
3,912,855
00:08:54



What's the issue?

Have you tried watching the video?

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57018278/

@stickynotememo video is ok but both Explorer and VLC think it lasts 23 hours and 36 minutes.

@Destroy666 about 23 hours longer than what it should be

Did you try redoing the concat? Maybe it's just a glitch.
